# PHP: Installing doctrine in project

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I am currently trying to run Doctrine in a custom (own) project, which isn't based on any popular framework.

I've been able to do the following for my current bootstrap.php;

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', dirname(__FILE__) );
$classLoader->register(); // register on SPL autoload stack
```

However I have a strong feeling that this is far from enough and I can't find any documentation which clearly states what I should do next.

Running `$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root:root@192.168.1.4/myTable', 'doctrine');` will make my PHP file to start throwing errors (Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine_Manager' not found) - so I am pretty sure that I have not completed the bootstrap.php properly.

What should I do to make Doctrine run as intended in my own project?

Comment: Hi BenV - it's the 2.0 version!

Comment: Feelin slightly retarded not being able to include a PHP file properly after working with PHP for many years, but the bounty is ON!

Comment: could you show your directory structure?

Comment: Hi Xzyfer. Directory structure is just one folder that I untarred the official Doctirne tarball into. Here's the info I followed: *3.1.1.1. PEAR or Tarball Download* http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html

Comment: Sorry I stupid misread the question. I'm fairly certain there is no Doctrine_Manager in Doctrine 2. There's an EntityManager. `Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root:root@192.168.1.4/myTable', 'doctrine');` this is Doctrine 1 code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work your way through extensive doctrine [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/manual/en) on the project website, it walks you through step by step what's required for a proper doctrine bootstrap

**Added from comment on question**

I'm fairly certain there is no Doctrine_Manager in Doctrine 2. There's an EntityManager. `Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root:root@192.168.1.4/myTable', 'doctrine');` this is Doctrine 1 code.

Either way, all classes should be namespaced `\Doctrine_Manager`

Here are some good reference for you:

[Doctrine 1 to Doctrine 2](http://css.dzone.com/articles/doctrine-1-doctrine-2)

[Doctrine 2 - Not the same old PHP ORM](http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/doctrine-2-not-the-same-old-php-orm) Slide 44 is what you are after

Comment: Thats what's getting my head to explode. I can't find a good example of how to set the latest (2.0) version up without using ZEND, Codeigniter or Symphony....

Comment: small typo in your link - s/b "Doctrine 1 to Doctrine **2**".

Comment: Hi Xzyfer. Thanks for your links - I will check them out and see if I can get it running!